# Rewriting partial differential equations with a matrix of coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

In a course on partial differential equations, it was said that a PDE can be rewritten using a matrix of coefficients. This means that, for example,

$$ a_{11}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + 2a_{12}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} + a_{22}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} $$

can be written as

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

However, I don't get how you would go from the second equation to the first equation. I get that 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + a_{12}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
a_{12}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + a_{22}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\end{bmatrix} $$ 
but how do you obtain the first equation (the one in PDE form) out of

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + a_{12}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
a_{12}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + a_{22}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\end{bmatrix} ?$$

I think my misunderstanding of the derivation comes down to not knowing what exactly is meant by the notation $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a matter of notation. Multiplying $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ by an expression is understood ar deriving the expression with respect to $x$ or $y$.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + a_{12} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ 
a_{21} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + a_{22} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( a_{11} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + a_{12} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( a_{21} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + a_{22} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
$$

which yields

$$
a_{11} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+(a_{12}+a_{21})\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}+a_{22} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
$$

Comment: So in $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}$, the first entry derives the top of the coefficient matrix with respect to x and the second entry derives the bottom of the coefficient matrix with respect to x? In my mind this seems counterintuitive as $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ seems to refer to the left part of the coefficient matrix and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ seems to refer to the right part of the matrix, the way it is written.

Comment: @SlowRoller This is how you multiply a row vector by a column vector, it is not supposed to achieve the "visual effect" you refer.

Comment: Got it, thank you!